# Typescript does not recognize a destructured property

Tags: typescript

I have the following response type which I am trying to destructure with the `unwrapFirstProperty` function.

```
type MyResponse <T extends string> = {
  [key in T]: { message: string; status: number; }
}

function unwrapFirstProperty<T>(response: T): {
  return Object.values(response)[0];
}

const response = { SOME_RESPONSE: { status: 200, message: 'success' } };
const property = unwrapFirstProperty<MyResponse<'SOME_RESPONSE'>>(response); // of type any for some reason
```

Typescript thinks the return type of the function is `any` rather than `{ message: string; status: number; }`. Why is that and what can I do to make sure the Typescript predicts the correct type? If I unwrap a single property on the object I am left with the only value of the object right?

[Reproduced on the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEDOYD2A7J0A8AVKEAHsBOgCZJRLABOAlugOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2gGsIIKAyi4AugC4uUALbIkAQ0YRZ1ekwDcVYMuABXJLPSH5AIwg1dAX273uAM0PoAxsDoYorgO41lMAAxOhpqAAUaVEgaUDxmAAoaZDRMdQkASllOWy5eKGSjGnQoAHkLACsIDwA6ADdlABtDZCSUjCwM-gAGSW0Hbm43DuAC9rT2OQBlUpgAUQB9eDmp8NKAOSm57L0DY1kAJm7ugBoFJVV0gHIkQzc3JSuoXNt%204cxRsCiY0Em-AOCoQi32scTgiBQHQg2CuM3mSxWa02cyuzESyUhaQyugA9DioKgnFBQJAoMp0KInKgaFRUIoxsokBhuEA)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx2rN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Here's a TS playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBKEDOYD2A7J0A8AVKEAHsBOgCZJRLABOAlugOYB8UAvFAN4BQUUA2gGsIIKAyi4AugC4uUALbIkAQ0YRZ1ekwDcVYMuABXJLPSH5AIwg1dAX273uAM0PoAxsDoYorgO41lMAAxOhpqAAUaVEgaUDxmAAoaZDRMdQkASllOWy5eKGSjGnQoAHkLACsIDwA6ADdlABtDZCSUjCwM-gAGSW0Hbm43DuAC9rT2OQBlUpgAUQB9eDmp8NKAOSm57L0DY1kAJm7ugBoFJVV0gHIkQzc3JSuoXNt+4cxRsCiY0Em-AOCoQi32scTgiBQHQg2CuM3mSxWa02cyuzESyUhaQyugA9DioKgnFBQJAoMp0KInKgaFRUIoxsokBhuEA

Comment: you say "of type `any` for some reason" but it's not `any`, it's `{}`, as annotated by your code.  Can you make sure your example actually demonstrates what you're asking about?  Otherwise I have to transform the question before trying to answer it and hope that it's what you meant.

Comment: That has sneaked in while I was copying the code. There shouldn't be a return type of `{}`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first property"? These two objects are technically the same type: (`{ status: 200, message: 'success' }`, and `{ message: 'success', status: 200 }`), so you are relying on typescript to infer runtime type information...that's not what typescript does

Comment: Not really runtime if I am saying to always give me a single value of an object which is always going to be returned with a single property. The objects aren't the same as first one clearly has one key with the response's name e.g. `SOME_RESPONSE` followed by the rest of the response. That's the purpose of the function - to destructure whatever's inside the single property.

Comment: Still the same problem. The type for `{ SOME_RESPONSE: { status: 200, message: 'success' } }` is exactly the same as the type for `{ SOME_RESPONSE: { message: 'success', status: 200 } }`. So essentially for typescript to know the return type for `unwrapFirstProperty`, it has to know the order of the objects inside `SOME_RESPONSE`, but this order has no guarantees....Try running `Object.values({ status: 200, message: 'success' })` and `Object.values({ message: 'success', status: 200 })`, and you will see how the output changes.

Comment: `any` or `unknown` is the "right" output because the compiler does not know that an object has no excess properties.  If you don't want to worry about that you can make `unwrapFirstProperty` generic and return `T[keyof T]` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoJA9m).  Note that this can have weird results with excess properties, as stated.

Comment: If you are okay with that I can write up an answer, but please fix your example code and playground link first.  Your code example has a broken annotation and the playground link has not been updated.  If you're not okay with that then please elaborate on unmet use cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
function unwrapFirstProperty<T>(response: T): T[keyof T] {
  return Object.values(response)[0];
}
```

`Object.values` has a return type of `any[]`, therefore `unwrapFirstProperty` returns `any`. Explicitly adding a return type narrows it down to the desired type.